# When Installing Ubuntu through virtual box I get an error

Tags: installation, virtualbox

When Installing Ubuntu through virtual box I get an error

> This kernel requres an X86-64 CPU, but only detected an I686 CPU.
>
> Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

How do I fix this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ut2.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a 64-bit version of Ubuntu on a 32-bit computer. Go back to [the download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and under "Choose your flavor", choose "32-bit".

Comment: I have a 64 bit PC and it holds 32/86 bit apps

Comment: BUT IT WORKED! THANKS!!

Comment: Of course you can install 64-bit Ubuntu, even on a 32-bit host provided your CPU supports VZ-x/AMD-V. Its only a settings issue. **No need to download another installation CD.**